# Error in Copying only Value of a cell in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
Set startRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("a65536").End(xlUp)
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B" & lastrowA).Copy startRange1.Offset(1, 2).Value
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & lastrowA).Copy startRange1.Offset(1, 1)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

I just want to copy the cell values and not the formulas in it as I get problems when I copy it to other sheet and save the file. I have tried value2 also but it doesn't work. please help Thanks.

Comment: Where are the lines to set the Range `startRange1`, `lastrowA`? Using **a65536** is legacy. Once you copied a range, you need to adjust the offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to just paste values, you need to use the [`PasteSpecial`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx)-method.

Change your code to:

```
Set startRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("a65536").End(xlUp)
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B" & lastrowA).Copy
startRange1.Offset(1, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & lastrowA).Copy
startRange1.Offset(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

and I believe it should work as intended. You may also want to paste the numberformats, in which case you change `xlPasteValues` to `xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats`. For more details on what you can do with `PasteSpecial`, I recommend you to have a look at the website I linked to above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, easier to understand.

```
Sub PasteThem()
    Dim oRngCopy As Range, oRngPasteTo As Range, lastrowA As Long
    lastrowA = 123 ' Whatever you get this from...
    ' Locate where to start pasting
    Set oRngPasteTo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    ' Sets Range 1 to copy
    Set oRngCopy = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B" & lastrowA)
    ' Copy the Range
    oRngCopy.Copy
    oRngPasteTo.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ' Adjust the Range to start pasting
    Set oRngPasteTo = oRngPasteTo.Offset(oRngCopy.Rows + 1, 0)
    ' Sets Range 2 to copy
    Set oRngCopy = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & lastrowA)
    ' Copy the Range
    oRngCopy.Copy
    oRngPasteTo.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ' Clean Up
    Set oRngCopy = Nothing
    Set oRngPasteTo = Nothing
End Sub
```